# How can I create a program to create multiple files from one template with different values inside?

Tags: ruby, url, redirect, selenium

I need to create 1500+ ruby files from a template for some testing I'm doing with Selenium.

The template looks like this:

```
class $CLASS_NAME

require "spec"

attr_accessor :title

include Spec::Example::ExampleGroupMethods
include Spec::Matchers


def initialize  
  @title = "$OLD_URL -> $NEW_URL"
end


def execute(selenium)
  selenium.open "$OLD_URL"
  sleep 1
  puts 'Opening...'
  sleep 1
  url = selenium.get_location
  puts 'Grabbing location...'
  sleep 1
  puts 'The URL is ' + url 
  puts 'Doing match...'
  sleep 1
  /$NEW_URL/.match(url).should_not be nil

  puts "\n##### Success! #####\n\r"

end # execute
```

I have a load of URL's I need to insert - one into each file, replacing '$OLD_URL' and '$NEW_URL'.

Is there anyway to do something like this?

> x = 0
>   while  (x < 1500)
>   {
>   open template.rb
>   find all instances of $CLASS_NAME and replace with xxx from classnames.txt
>   find all instances of $OLD_URL and replace with xxx from listofurls.csv
>   find all instances of $NEW_URL and replace with xxx from listofurls.csv
>   save file as ('redirect_' + 'x++')
>   x++
>   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do it is using the `ERB` library.

The code below will generate two files according to predefined template.

```
require "erb"

File.open("template.erb") do |io|
  template = ERB.new io.read

  files = {:anecdote => "There are 10 types of people in the world.",
           :story => "Once upon a time..."}

  files.each do |file, contents|
    File.open "#{file}.txt", "w" do |out| 
      out.puts template.result binding
    end
  end
end
```

When `template.erb` looks like:

```
Title <%= file %>
<%= "=" * 40 %>
<%= contents %>
<%= "=" * 40 %>
```

Here is the contents of `aneqdote.txt`:

```
Title anecdote
========================================
There are 10 types of people in the world.
========================================
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm after but I need to create 1500+ files with three different variables in each file. Plus it needs to read the values from an external file (csv)...

Comment: Use the `CSV` library. It's pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents of `template.rb` to a string, then use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817) to edit the template inside the loop and save the modified template.